# Imagelist неправильная работа

Tags: c#, listview

Пишу для себя небольшую программку. Появилась проблема с imageList.
Ближе к делу: прога принимает картинку с сервера в формате base64 дешифрует и вставляет в listview таким образом.

```
Image im = Base64ToImage(base64);

imageList1.Images.Add(im);
listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;
listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;

listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem 
{ 
    ImageIndex = id, 
    Text = " " + location.Split('-')[1] 
});
```

Картинка добавляется все ок. Выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но! Как быть если я хочу удалить строку? Вернее даже не строку а картинку.
Строку удаляю вот так:

```
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(id);
```

Но картинка остается в image list. Её удаляю так:

```
imageList1.Images.RemoveAt(id);
```

И теперь самое забавное. Как бы в imageliste картинки то уже и нету но в listview она по прежнему отображается. Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жмякаю удалить. С imagelist удаляется последняя картинка, но в listview ничего не меняется.
Жмякаю удалить. С imagelist удаляется предпоследняя картинка, но в listview ничего не меняется.
Жмякаю удалить. С imagelist удаляется первая картинка(последняя в imagelist), в listview не остается ни одной картинки :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит? Как правильно удалять? Подскажите куда копать. Гугл гуглил но про Remove там мало инфы.

Comment: Для того чтобы работало оповещение UI об изменении состава коллекции следует использовать `ObservableCollection<T>`. Для того чтобы оповещать UI об изменении отдельных свойств объекта, эти свойства должны реализовывать вызов события `PropertyChanged()`, а класс этого объекта должен реализовывать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Это азы привязки (байдинга).

Comment: @Bulson, а тут случайно не `WinForms`, мне кажется тут это работать не будет, вот в `WPF` сработает. Или я ошибаюсь? Тут все нужно перерисовывать, чтобы изменилось визуально.

Comment: @DenisBubnov я действительно не обратил внимание, что этот вопрос может быть про `WinForms`. Ну, тогда автор вопроса сам себе злой буратино, что не указал нужный тег.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, кстати, интересная вещь, что новички даже, похоже, не подозревают про существование `WPF`.  Потому указывают только один тег `C#`. Думаю, это связано с тем, что в большинстве обучающих материалов для начинающих используют либо консольные приложения, либо `WinForms`.

Comment: @Bulson, кстати, соглашусь, что многие не знают про `WPF`, думаю, узнают многие про него после того, как начинают изучать `MVVM`. И да, обучающих материалов очень много, что получается так, что новые технологии остаются в тени.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Разобрался методом тыка и перебора картинок. Хотя сам так до конца и не понял что сделал, но это работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void Refresh(int id)
    {
        int c = _clientSockets.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = i.ToString(); listView1.Items[i].ImageIndex = i + 1; });
        }

        listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { imageList1.Images.RemoveAt(id); });

        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listView1.Items[i].ImageIndex = i; });
        }
    }
```